# Syntax Error While Learning Loops

Tags: python

I'm a beginner into Chapter 6 of "How to Think like a Computer Scientist", section on Iteration/While Loops.

In the book, a syntax for 2-dimensional table is as follow:

```
i=1
while i <= 6:
  print 2*i, '   ', 
  i=i+1 
print
```

However, doing so results in a syntax error. The terminal gave

```
File "<stdin>", line 4
    print
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I know that the second print statement is unnecessary and removing it would correct the error; however, a line in the later section of the book explains that the second print statement is intended to create a new line after printing a horizontal table. Hence I believe it could be a typo error. I tried several variations but still could not come to a solution.

Comment: why 5th line has a blank `print` statement?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary:  It'll print a blank line.  Quick way of writing `print '\n'`, and it won't skip more than one line..

Comment: @Makoto It will print a blank line but it is not the same as `print '\n'`

Comment: @Makoto that depends on the python version, in python 3.x it prints out `<built-in function print>` and in 2.x it's `'\n'`, and I think OP is using 3.x here.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary:  The error would have occurred at line 3 instead, then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It seems to be a problem with the shell**

When executing the snippet you posted as a file, it runs. You seem to run in in a shell (`<stdin>` hints that), and in the shell, the same snippet does not work for me (python 2.7.2 on Ubuntu) too.

Comment: Okay, I think that solves it! Yes, I was trying to run it from the Command Line. But I don't think the book tried to run it in a .py file, and instead I think it was trying to run on the terminal too.

Comment: Why is the shell any different to a file? Just curious

Answer (score 3):

You do not mention if you have the stuff in a file or if you enter it manually.

In the latter case, your terminal looks like

```
>>> i=1
>>> while i <= 6:
...   print 2*i, '   ',
...   i=i+1
... print
  File "<stdin>", line 4
    print
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

That is, in order to terminate the intended `while` clause, you have to enter an empty line:

```
>>> i=1
>>> while i <= 6:
...   print 2*i, '   ',
...   i=i+1
...
```

And here execution already happens.

Another workaround could be to enter the stuff you wantto execute in an `if 1` clause:

```
>>> i=1
>>> if 1:
...  while i <= 6:
...   print 2*i, '   ',
...   i=i+1
...  print
...
2     4     6     8     10     12
>>>
```

Comment: why is it, that in order to terminate the while clause, you need an empty line in the shell? why doenst the shell just looks for normal python code, until a blank line is entered?

Answer (score 1):

<del>...I think that it's that serial comma at the end of the `print` statement.  As said before, if you're using Python 3, it turns into a function (e.g. `print(2*i)`).</del>

**EDIT:**  After looking a bit closer, it would be easier to simply remove the extra `print`.  It isn't necessary.  If you're printing out a horizontal table, there's nothing wrong with appending a newline character to your initial print statement.

Comment: Yeap, that's exactly what I did. I was seeking clarification though regarding what the book printed intentionally; with the second print statement intended to print a blank line.